# MAX function returning a row

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables:

**Proveedor**

```
+-----+---------+-----------+
| sid | pnombre | direccion |
+-----+---------+-----------+
|   1 | P1      | La Paz    |
|   2 | Paco    | 31 Pte    |
|   3 | Pepe    | 31 Pte    |
+-----+---------+-----------+
```

**Parte**

```
+-----+-----------+-------+
| pid | pnombre   | color |
+-----+-----------+-------+
|   1 | Palanca 1 | Gris  |
|   2 | Palanca 2 | Gris  |
|   3 | Palanca 3 | Verde |
|   4 | Palanca 4 | azul  |
+-----+-----------+-------+
```

**Catalogo**

```
+-----+-----+-------+
| sid | pid | costo |
+-----+-----+-------+
|   1 |   1 |   100 |
|   1 |   2 |   120 |
|   2 |   3 |    90 |
|   1 |   3 |   150 |
|   1 |   4 |   150 |
+-----+-----+-------+
```

I'm trying to get the "id of the 'parte'(part) with the highest 'costo' (cost) of the user with name = 'P1' "

My query is this one:

```
SELECT pid, MAX(costo)
FROM catalogo
WHERE sid IN(SELECT sid
             FROM proveedor
             WHERE pnombre = "P1")
GROUP BY pid;
```

But my result is this:

```
+-----+------------+
| pid | MAX(costo) |
+-----+------------+
|   1 |        100 |
|   2 |        120 |
|   3 |        150 |
|   4 |        150 |
+-----+------------+
```

And I only spect to get 1 row which have to be

```
+-----+------------+
| pid | MAX(costo) |
+-----+------------+
|   3 |        150 |
+-----+------------+
```

So the question, What am I doing wrong with my query? how can I return 1 row using MAX() ?

NOTE:
I already solved this with another query.
But ***I'm trying to understand how MAX() works***

Query (2) to solve without MAX():

```
SELECT pid, costo 
FROM catalogo 
WHERE sid IN (SELECT sid 
              FROM proveedor 
              WHERE pnombre = "P1")  
ORDER BY costo DESC 
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Did you realize have a tie for cost 150 ?

Comment: BTW is better for performance use `inner join` as gordon answer intead of `IN`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with `MAX`is doesn't bring the row related to that value. Because like this case the `MAX` value can match several rows.

That is why in the Gordon solution you sort the cost and get the one on the top the get the highest value. But in that case you lost the ties.

**[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/24421/4)**

In this solution,

- you first calculate the max value
- then bring all the records matching that value
- finally select the one belong to `P1`

.

```
  SELECT pid, c.costo
  FROM
  (
    SELECT MAX(costo) costo
    FROM proveedor p
    INNER JOIN Catalogo c
       ON p.sid = c.sid
    WHERE p.pnombre = "P1"
   ) mcosto
   inner join Catalogo c
    on mcosto.costo = c.costo
   inner join proveedor p
    on p.sid = c.sid
   WHERE p.pnombre = "P1";
```

Comment: So for `MAX()` is better to use it when isn't related to multiple values like in this example right?

Comment: `MAX()` work great when you use `group by`  for example to get the max value for each proveedor .

Comment: Okay Thanks.
Also a syntax question, on `SELECT MAX(costo) costo` why you left a whitespace instead of a comma? or what does this code mean?

Comment: I create an alias to the result of a function is equivalent to `SELECT MAX(costo) AS costo` when you use a function the db usually create a default name for that field. In this case i want the field be name `costo`

Answer (score 3):

If you are learning SQL, I would advise you to learn explicit `join` syntax.  In addition, you can get a row with the maximum cost by using `order by` and `limit` -- aggregation functions are not required:

```
select c.pid, c.costo
from catalogo c join
     proveedor p
     on c.sid = p.sid
where p.pnombre = 'P1'
order by c.cost desc
limit 1;
```

Comment: Thanks, I forgot to say that I already solved with "order by" (I've just edited my question)